# I can not see logs in soapUI groovy script test screen

Tags: logging, groovy, jar, external, soapui

I'm using an external jar in order to test my apps and this jar publishes some logs in soapui.log file

However, I can not see them in log frames of groovy screen (soapui log, http log, jetty log, script log etc.)

I tail soapui.log file but it is very time consuming to run everything on one window and check results in another..

```
import org.jsmpp.example.*;
import org.jsmpp.bean.*;

String host     = "xxxx"
int port        = xxx
String user     = "xxx"
String pwd      = "xx"
String sysType  = "xx"
String serviceType  = "xxx"

session = new simpleSubmit();
session.bind(host,port,user,pwd);
```

when I run this script, I see the lines below in soapui.log file

```
2012-12-05 02:31:43,150 INFO  [SMPPSession] Connected
2012-12-05 02:31:43,151 INFO  [SMPPSession] Starting PDUReaderWorker with processor degree:3 ...
2012-12-05 02:31:43,165 INFO  [SMPPSession] Starting EnquireLinkSender
2012-12-05 02:31:58,221 INFO  [SMPPSession] PDUReaderWorker stop
2012-12-05 02:31:58,660 INFO  [SMPPSession] EnquireLinkSender stop
```

at first my intention was showing these lines in soapUI GUI (log.output screen or soapUI.log scren). 
But If I can store them it would be better. Thus I can verify my test cases..