# How do I transfer the console log created from my .jar which I use in SoapUI to the groovy Log Output of the SoapUI UI

Tags: groovy, jar, soapui

this is my very first Question, please have mercy for any mistakes I make.

I recently got the task to automate something that is using soapUI and a bunch of java tools. So far many the tools have done things like comparing xmls that are returned from my soapUI requests. This has been done by hand, but now I would like to automaticly compare those xmls in my SoapUI test case.
I already managed to include the jar and also do the comparing just fine. The only issue I have is, that any console log from my jar (e.g System.out.println(...)) is of course printed to the log of soapUI itself and not the groovy Output Log in my UI.
I can already feel like it will be extremly annoying to debug once there are problems, so I am searching for a way to display those logs to the groovy Output Log directly.

Example:

in groovy:

```
import de.intersoft.log.Logger

Logger logger = new Logger()
logger.printLn()
```

from my jar:

```
public void printLn() {
        System.out.println("out - println");
    }
```

The soapui.log contains the "out - println" but the groovy Log Output does not.

So far I have not been able to find anything, does anyone know a way to do it? Someone asked this question 10 years age which is the same problem as mine, but so far no answers are submitted.

[I can not see logs in soapUI groovy script test screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565999/i-can-not-see-logs-in-soapui-groovy-script-test-screen)

What I do not want is to just return values in my methods that contain those logs, because for that I'd have to rewrite all the tools and I want a smarter and easier solution.

Thanks in advance :)